# Using extremely small or invisible surface view using opencv for android

Tags: android, opencv, surfaceview

I am trying to create an application which captures and processes camera frames using a hidden or invisible or extremely small (say dimensions of 1x1 pixels) over Android device. However, I am facing a weird problem: If the size of the surface view is less than 300x300, the application says that "it seems that your device does not support camera (or it is locked). Application will be closed". I am using opencv's JavaCameraView class for previewing the camera frames.

Is there any way in which I can achieve this?

Comment: Android OCV 2.4.8, has a mixed sample tutorial which uses JavaCameraView. I have been able to modify the code, to silently capture & process frames on the background. Is this what you are looking for? If yes, I would suggest you to work with that sample by modifying it. Its easy.

Comment: Yes @Suddev. That is what I am looking for. Thank you for the pointer. Can you post some details as an answer?